# How to Select a line only text with special character using regex

Tags: regex

Input:

```
1.\frac{[a+b]}{xjch}

2.\frac{pqz}{xjch}
```

Wanted output is

```
1.[a+b]/(xjch)

2.(pqz)/(xjch)
```

My regex is:

```
\\frac\{(.{2,})\}\{(.{2,})\}
```

if i apply this regex, 
the  output will be,

```
1.([a+b])/(xjch)

2.(pqz)/(xjch)
```

But i dont want `()` in `[a+b]`. ie if any special character inside the `{...}`, the round bracket should not come. otherwise, (Without special characters) ,the round bracket should come like `(pqz)`,`(xjch)`.

I want two regex for both 1. and 2. then only i will get wanted output.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I think the parentheses are just representations of the groups in whichever tool you're using? In truth you're only getting [a+b] and xjch for the first one, and pqz and xjch for the last one.

Comment: How does one add parentheses by "applying" a regex?

Comment: To do a replacement with conditions in C#, you need to use a callback function, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442245/c-sharp-replace-with-callback-function-like-in-as3

Answer (score 0):

you can write a `Regex` that contain **within** the bracket and replace the group 1 and 2 with a condition

```
if(nextchar == "[") 
    TypeOfYourInstuction = 1; 
else 
    TypeOfYourInstuction = 2;`
```

and this regex is

```
\\frac\{\[?([a-zA-Z1-9\+]{2,})\]?\}\{\[?([a-zA-Z1-9\+]{2,})\]?\}
```

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/18

but as you mention it, you can write two regex for first type and the second one:

```
the first regex: \[[^\]]{2,}\] // Demo = http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/20
the second regex: \{[^\[^\}]*\}  // Demo = http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/19
```

you have to replace the second type with parenthesis